# What is the correct PVC configuration in AKS for multi-zone storage?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

We have an AKS cluster set up with a multiple availability zone node pool. Using the `default` storage class, if a Pod needs to move to another node and the only available node is in a different region, the Pod can't start up because the storage is stuck in the original region. Do any of the other built-in storage classes support the relocation of workloads across multi-zone pools?

```yaml
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: data
  namespace: $NAMESPACE
  labels:
    service: db
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: default
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 4Gi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use below configurations depending on your need.

**Example StorageClass.yaml**

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: azurefile
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_ZRS
  location: eastus
  storageAccount: azure_storage_account_name  
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
    values:
    - eastus2-1
    - eastus2-2
    - eastus2-3
```

According to that following skuName are available in Azure —

- **Standard_LRS** — standard locally redundant storage (LRS)
- **Standard_GRS** — standard geo-redundant storage (GRS)
- **Standard_ZRS** — standard zone redundant storage (ZRS)
- **Standard_RAGRS** — standard read-access geo-redundant storage (RA-GRS)
- **Premium_LRS** — premium locally redundant storage (LRS)
- **Premium_ZRS** — premium zone redundant storage (GRS)

References: [K8s Allowed Topologies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#allowed-topologies), [AKS - Availability Zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/availability-zones), [AKS - StorageClasses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-storage#storage-classes)